# Unknown Host Exception in jmeter

Tags: http, jmeter

[image]I am trying run my first test case in jmeter. I am getting this error.
java.net.UnknownHostException. ?

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: google.com
```

Comment: The screen capture doesn't fit your description (in respect with the domain name). Does it work specifiying 'http' as protocol and forcing '80' as Port Number ?

Answer (score 0):

Check you have configured Enterprise proxy as per this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server

Options:

- -H
  [proxy server hostname or ip address]
- -P
  [proxy server port]
- -N
  [nonproxy hosts] (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
- -u
  [username for proxy authentication - if required]
- -a
  [password for proxy authentication - if required]

Example:

> jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost